# Remove all elements with a certain child (nested at least 2 levels in), in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, conditional-statements

Say I have 2 HTML objects.

The first is 1 `div` object:

```
<div class="d1">
</div>
```

The second is a 3 `div` object with respective nesting:

```
<div class="d1">
    <div class="d2">
        <div class="d3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the third is the deepest.

Let's also assume I have a webpage with 50 elements of the first object, and 50 elements of the second object.

How could I delete all HTML objects containing a certain element nested deep inside them (in this case, the element with `.d3`).

I could do:

```
let f = document.querySelector('.d1');
let s = document.querySelector('.d2');
let t = document.querySelector('.d3');

if (t.parentNode == s && s.parentNode == f) {
    f.remove();
}
```

In jQuery I could also do:

```
if( $(f)[1].hasChildNodes() ) {
    f.remove();
}
```

What is an efficient way to do that in vanilla JS?

### Update:

I used a 3 level object just for the sake of a simple example. Please assume there might be much more children we could target, say, the 300th child. For example, if the object includes child 30, or 300 (instead of 3), remove the object. One answer suggests adding an `id` for the relevant child (say, child number 55). I think this is a good approach to cover the larger collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select such nested elements using `".d1 > .d2 > .d3"` selector, and then remove them using `removeChild` or `remove` function.

```js
var d3Elements = document.querySelectorAll(".d1 > .d2 > .d3");

for(var i = 0; i < d3Elements.length; i++) {
  console.log(d3Elements[i]);
  d3Elements[i].parentElement.removeChild(d3Elements[i]);
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  D1
</div>
<div class="d1">
  D1
  <div class="d2">
    D2
    <div class="d3">
      D3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: or if the structure is not necessarily in that format, simply document.querySelectorAll(".d1 .d3")

Comment: @andrewf Yes, good point. I knew about that, but avoided it assuming they might not want to remove elements if they are direct descendants of `.d1`: Something like `.d1 > .d3`

Comment: Nice, thanks @NisargShah. I guess it would be best to add an ID and use `querySelectorAll` on all these having the ID (or, if we cannot add ID, all elements with a certain `textContent`, or with more than X number of children).

Answer (score 1):

Set an id for the `div` for which you want to remove all children:

```
<div class="d1">
    <div id="removchildren" class="d2">
        <div class="d3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Get that element and remove inner html

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("removchildren");
myDiv.innerHTML = '';
```

You can also traverse and make it dynamic using `myDiv.childNodes`

Comment: Thank you, what did you mean by "make it dynamic"?

Comment: I meant you could use something like this `myDiv.childNodes[0].innerHtml = ''` if there are multiple items inside `d2 `.